# Image won't render in the table, please assist

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, reportlab

I am trying to render an image generated by MathplotLib into a pdf created by ReportLab. Please fix.

```
    graph1 = Image(filename='Graphs/AvgAnnMedCostPerEE.png',x=50,y=50,width=None,height=None,path='Graphs/AvgAnnMedCostPerEE.png')#,kind='direct',mask='auto',hAlign='CENTER',)
    first_graph_table_header = [["Average Annual Medical Cost Per Employee",""],
                                ["",graph1]]

    first_graph_page_style = TableStyle([('SPAN', (0, 0), (1, 0))])
                                     # ('ALIGN', (0, 3), (8, 3), 'CENTER'),
                                     # ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (8, 0), 'CENTER'),
                                     # ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (8, 0), 'MIDDLE'),
                                     # ('VALIGN', (2, 3), (6, 3), 'MIDDLE'),
                                     # ('BACKGROUND', (0, 2), (8, 2), colors.HexColor('#305496')),
                                     # ('BACKGROUND', (0, 3), (8, 3), colors.HexColor('#b4c6e7')),
                                     # ('BACKGROUND', (8, 2), (8, 3), colors.orange),
                                     # ('FONT', (0, 2), (-9, -2), 'Helvetica-Bold', 10),
                                     # ('FONT', (2, 3), (-7, -1), 'Helvetica-Bold', 12),
                                     # ('FONT', (3, 3), (-3, -1), 'Helvetica-Bold', 10),
                                     # ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 2), (-9, -2), colors.white)
                                     # ])

    g1 = Table(first_graph_table_header, colWidths=[14.75, 161],
               rowHeights=[5.5*mm, 2*inch])
    g1.setStyle(first_graph_page_style)
    self.story.append(g1)
    self.story.append(Image(filename='Graphs/AvgAnnMedCostPerEE.png',x=50,y=50,width=None,height=None,path='Graphs/AvgAnnMedCostPerEE.png'))


    self.story.append(PageBreak())

# def createGraphs(self, canvas, doc):

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = CoverPage_Index()
    t.run()
```

I keep getting AttributeError: Image instance has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. After a bit of madness, I understood that the reason is a name clashing. So this is the solution that worked for me.
You need a flowable Image, but the name *Image* is probably not unique in your imported classes.
First, give to the Image class you want to use a name that you are sure is unique at the import time; I used GNAA (who on earth would write a class named GNAA?).

```
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Image as GNAA
```

then you can use it to pick an image. In this example, the image is  in the same directory as the python program. IMPORTANT: use a jpg, because a png may not work:

```
logo = "logo.jpg"
im = GNAA(logo, width=200, height=38)
story.append(im)
```

Now the Image is the correct one, flowable and with all the correct parameters needed.
I did non investigate where the doppelganger of the Image is, but this trick works fine.